# Was my prayer valid if there was a picture of a fictional character a few meters in front of me?

Tags: halal-haram, salat, fiqh, makruh

I was getting ready to pray Tahajjud early in the morning. I was rushing because I had to take a shower and Fajr time was getting close. There was a picture of a fictional non-human character 1 or 2 meters in front of where I usually pray. Since I was in a rush, I told myself I'll move the picture to somewhere else in the room after the shower. But when I finished my shower and got ready to pray, I completely forgot to remove the picture out of the way. I noticed the picture in front of me once tahajjud time was over.

I understand that my salah will be makruh tahrimi, but was it valid? Was my salah useless?

I also made a passionate dua regarding a hardship I'm facing in life. Was that dua also invalid?

Answer (score 1):

Aslamu Walaykum

Muslims always forget and do mistakes, so if you forgot it is okay. Your dua and prayers are not invalid because you didn't know. Allah is the most forgiving, and he was watching you. So do not worry